# pandas dataframe interpolating missing days

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with several columns. I have dates for business days excluding holidays and some other random holes. Is there an interpolation method for filling in these gaps and and getting a dataframe for all business days?

Answer (score 4):

You may use reindex() method of DataFrame:

```
x = pd.date_range('2013-01-01','2013-01-07',freq='D')
y = range(7)
df=pd.DataFrame(index=x,data=y,columns=['value'])
```

To add missing days (like holidays) you need to reindex it:

```
x2= pd.date_range('2013-01-01','2013-01-07',freq='4H')
df2=df.reindex(x2)
```

Then you may fill the gaps in values using interpolate() method of Series (different interpolation methods are available):

```
df2.value=df2.value.interpolate(method='linear')
```

Comment: How would you modify this for the case where x has multiple columns? Also, why do I get the error "File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 3176, in interpolate
    inds[invalid], inds[valid], values[firstIndex:][valid])
TypeError: array cannot be safely cast to required type" on the interpolate line?

Comment: What's the dtype of your series? 0.13 adds interpolation for DataFrames. It should be released soonish.